# How can I copy contents of one xml file to other empty xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 xml files. first.xml has some elements in it. second.xml file is empty it just have dtd declaration.  I want to copy all nodes of first.xml to second.xml file using xslt. For this I have created xsl file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>   

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="file1" select="document('data/first.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="$file1@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$file1/)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

first.xml looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TestConfig PUBLIC "xyz.dtd" "xyz.dtd">
<TestConfig debug="false" disable="false" name="moduletests">

  <BeforeTests>
  <Test name="Test Configuration" type="helthcheck"/>
  </BeforeTests>

  <Test name='Test with SSL'  type='helthcheck'>
   <AttributeToAdd>
       <Script>
        <Source>
        </Source>
       </Script>
   </AttributeToAdd>
   </Test>

   <Test name='My test'  type='create'/>
</TestConfig>
```

Second.xml file looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myXSL.xsl"?>     
   <!DOCTYPE TestConfig  PUBLIC"xyz.dtd" "xyz.dtd">
   <TestConfig>
   </TestConfig>
```

Comment: A well-formed XML document must have a single root element. This means your second.xml is not well-formed, and so you won't be able to apply XSLT on it (well, in XSLT 1.0 at least)

Comment: @Tim : Assume root element is present in the second.xml

Comment: Neither `xsl:template match="$file1@*|node()"` nor `xsl:apply-templates select="$file1/)"` makes any sense, not even syntactically. Also you have not told described in any exact way how you want the output to look, or which errors you get. If you want to populate the root element of one document with the contents of another then simply use `<xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`. Of course the `copy-of` can be adjusted to e.g. `select="document('file2.xml')/*/node()"/>` for instance if you don't want to copy the root element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : Thanks !, I want to copy whatever present under root node.